# Polynomial fitting from robust linear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, robust, polynomial

I have run a robust linear mixed effects model to determine the standard deviation within subjects for a repeatability study on a new imaging device. The SDw was derived from the square root of the residual mean square. I have done this from over 100k observations and Grouped through the measurement range from 40 to 90.

I have then plotted the SDw for each point from 40 to 90 using a polynomial curve and obtained an R2 of 0.92.

My question is, is this a statistically sound method for use of polynomial ? I tried fitting a simple linear but it did not fit my data well.